# Prove $\int_{\ln(3)}^{+\infty}{\frac x{e^{2x}-9}}dx$ diverges

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need some help proving, that the integral
$$\int_{\ln(3)}^{+\infty}{\frac x{e^{2x}-9}}dx$$
diverges. I have tried applying a comparison test
$$\frac x{e^{2x}-9}=\frac x{(e^x-3)(e^x+3)}\ge \frac 1{(e^x-3)(e^x+e^x)}=\frac 12\frac 1{(e^x-3)e^x}, for\space x\in(\ln(3), +\infty)$$
which then implies
$$\int_{\ln(3)}^{+\infty}{\frac x{e^{2x}-9}}dx\ge\frac 12\int_{\ln(3)}^{+\infty}{\frac 1{(e^x-3)e^x}}dx=\begin{bmatrix}u:=e^x\\du:=e^xdx\end{bmatrix}=\frac 12\int_3^{+\infty}{\frac 1{(u-3)u^2}}du$$
but I can't think of an easy way to prove, that the last integral diverges.

Comment: I'm curious. Isn't the fact that $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow\ln{3}} \frac{x}{e^{2x}-9} = \infty$ enough to show that the integral must diverge?

Comment: @infinitezero, actually, it is not. Consider $\int_0^1\ln(x)dx$, while $\lim_{x\to 0^+}{\ln(x)}=-\infty$, the integral equals $-1$.

Comment: Good point. Still, the function diverges faster than log(x) ...

Comment: @infinitezero, the whole point is to shows what "fast enough" is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since$$\lim_{u\to3}\frac{\frac1{(u-3)u^2}}{\frac1{u-3}}=\frac19$$and $\int_3^4\frac1{u-3}\,\mathrm du$ diverges, then so does does $\int_3^4\frac1{(u-3)u^2}\,\mathrm du$ and therefore so does your integral.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

Note that $$\frac1{u^2(u-3)}=-\frac1{9u}-\frac1{3u^2}+\frac{1}{9(u-3)}$$

Can you proceed now?

Answer (score 0):

$\frac 1{u^2(u-3)}>0$ for $u\in(3;+\infty)$. Therefore, $\int_3^{+\infty}{\frac 1{u^2(u-3)}}du \ge\int_3^4{\frac 1{u^2(u-3)}}du$.

On this interval $\frac 1{u^2(u-3)}\ge\frac 1{16(u-3)}$. This implies, that
$$\int_3^4{\frac 1{u^2(u-3)}}du\ge\frac 1{16}\int_3^4{\frac 1{u-3}}du=\frac 1{16}[\ln(u-3)+C]_3^4=-\frac1{16}\lim_{u\to 3^+}{\ln(u-3)}=+\infty$$
From the chain of inequalities we can conclude, that the original integral diverges too.